# Vector spaces and intersections

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was thinking of the following problem lately:

> Suppose $V_1,V_2,V_3,V_4$ are vector subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^4$ of dimension $2$ such that $V_i\cap V_j=\{0\}$ for $i \neq j$. Is it true that we can find a two dimensional vector subspace of $\Bbb{R}^4$ such that $\dim V_i\cap W =1$ for $i=1,2,3,4$?

The same problem with all dimensions doubled was given to a Miklos Schweitzer competition in 2012.

Using a linear automorphism of $\Bbb{R}^4$ we can assume that $V_1=span\{e_1,e_2\},V_2=span\{e_3,e_4\}$ where $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ is the canonical base. It is rather easy to construct $W$ which satisfies $\dim W\cap V_i = 1$ for $i=1,2,3$ but I didn't manage connecting it to the fourth space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**$W$ may not always exist.** Here is a counter-example.

Following your notations, let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ be a basis of $\Bbb  R^4$ and let

$$V_1={\rm span}\{e_1, e_2\}, \quad V_2={\rm span}\{e_3, e_4\}.$$
Moreover, let

$$V_3={\rm span}\{e_1+ e_3, e_2+e_4\},\quad V_4={\rm span}\{e_1-e_4, e_2+e_3\}.$$ 
It is easy to check that those subspaces satisfy all the requirements. Now suppose $W$ is a two dimensional subspace of  $\Bbb  R^4$ and $\dim (W\cap V_1 )=\dim (W\cap V_2)=1$, so there are $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb R$, such that
$$ W={\rm span}\{ a e_1+be_2, c e_3+de_4\}.$$
Consider $u:=(a,b)$ and $v:=(c,d)$ as non-zero vectors in $\Bbb R^2$. Then direct calculation shows that $\dim (W\cap V_3)=1$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ are parallel, and $\dim (W\cap V_4)=1$ if and only if  $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular, i.e. those two conditions cannot be both satisfied simultaneously.

Comment: Nice counterexample.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: Thank you. Maybe I should mention that the example is a special case of the following observation. By choosing the basis $\{e_1,\dots, e_4\}$ appropriately, $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ can always be of the form given in my answer and at the same time, $V_4$ is spanned by a pair of vectors $(e_1,e_3)A+(e_2,e_4)B$, where $A$, $B$ and $A-B$ are invertible $2\times 2$ matrices. Then $W$ exists iff $A^{-1}B$ has a real eigenvalue. In my answer, $A$ is identity and $B$ is rotation by $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

What about
$$
V_1=span\{e_1,e_2\}, \quad V_2=span\{e_3,e_4\}, 
$$
$$
V_3=span\{e_1+e_3,e_2+e_4\}, \quad V_4=span\{e_1-e_3,e_2-e_4\}.
$$
These are all two-dimensional subspaces with $V_i\cap V_j=\{0\}$ for $i\ne j$.
Taking
$$
W=span\{e_1+e_2,e_3+e_4\}
$$
should answer the question: $dim(W\cap V_i)=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: I think the question is "Given _any_ four two-dimensional subspaces ...", not choosing a particular example where one can find $W$.

Comment: thank you, misread the question. Maybe the general case can be reduced to this case?